# Statically link with a library without exporting its functions

Tags: c++, linker, symbols, visual-studio-2012

I have a C++ library that compiles to a static library (say `foo.lib`). This `foo.lib` uses third-party static libraries (`lib1.lib`, `lib2.lib`, `lib3.lib`). I don't want to export these libraries' symbols by any form.
However the linkage fails, with the following error:

```
LNK1189 - "The limit of 65535 objects or members in a library has been exceeded".
```

Is there any solution for this? (The 3rd party libraries don't exist in a dynamic libraries version).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already google for this ?  May be this could help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at5879hx.aspx

Comment: @Christophe: yes, I did. The problem is that the 3rd party libraries have more than 64K symbols. This isn't something that I can change. I just wondered why does the linker try to export those symbols instead of exporting only the foo.lib ones.

Comment: Ok ! I wanted to suggest you to limit visibility of symbols in your own code, but if it's the third party library, it's a problme: it means that you have a static library, which purpose is to be linked, but that can obviously not be linked because it doesn't respect the constraints of the linker !

Comment: Do you really need all of .obj files that library contains? If not, you can try to unpack required `obj` files from `lib` file and link these files only.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select manually which symbols to export by using a `.def` file. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx

If not, you can pack yourself the third party libraries in one or more DLLs by explicitly writing which symbols to export (through a `.def` file too)